# Spring Boot: How to inject the same instance of a prototype scoped bean into a Spring Boot Test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I have a service class that uses a prototype scoped bean declared in the following way:

```
@Bean
@Scope(scopeName = SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = TARGET_CLASS)
MyBean myBean() {...}
```

And I have an integration test which looks like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    MyBean myBean;
    // tests follow here
}
```

**Problem:** I need exactly the same instance of `MyBean` in the test but Spring injects a different instance because the scope of the bean is 'prototype'.

**Question:** How to inject the same instance of a prototype scoped bean into a test?

Note: I cannot change the scope declaration of the bean.

Answer (score 2):

You have two approaches.

Override `MyBean` to make it a singleton bean :

```
@TestConfiguration
public class OverrideBeanConfigurationForTest {

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = SCOPE_SINGLETON)
    MyBean myBean() {...}
}
```

Or override it to return always the same bean :

```
@TestConfiguration
public class OverrideBeanConfigurationForTest {

    MyBean myBean;

    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = TARGET_CLASS)
    MyBean myBean() {
      if (myBean == null){ 
         myBean = new MyBean(...),
      }
      return myBean;
    }
}
```

Now import this configuration in your spring boot test and also specify  the property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` as that is `false` by default :

```
@SpringBootTest({"spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true"})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import(OverrideBeanConfigurationForTest.class)
class MyServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    MyBean myBean;
    // tests follow here
}
```

Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change anything and you insist on injecting the bean straight off then it is impossible.

The documentation clearly states:

> **The non-singleton prototype scope of bean deployment results in the creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific bean is made. That is, the bean is injected into another bean or you request it through a getBean() method call on the container.** As a rule, you should use the prototype scope for all stateful beans and the singleton scope for stateless beans.

You are injecting it into another bean.

[Prototype scoped beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype)